# Laravel 5.2 - Can't Update Multiple Images, Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, image-uploading, laravel-5

I'm trying to update the table field with multiple images form inside. The create form it's work fine, but the problem is when I'm trying to update it.

So here the controller of the update function:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $update = new Product($request->all());
    $product=Product::find($id);

    $picture = ''; 
    $images = [];
    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
    $files = $request->file('images');
    foreach($files as $file){
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $picture = date('His').$filename;
    $destinationPath = base_path() . '\public\images/';
    $file->move($destinationPath, $picture);
    $images[]=$picture;
    }
    }

    if (!empty($product['images'])) {
    $product['images'] = $images[0];
    $product['images2'] = $images[1];
    $product['images3'] = $images[2];
    $product['images4'] = $images[3];
    } else {
    unset($product['images']);
    }

    $product->update($update);
    return redirect('product');
}
```

If it's not clear enough, you can see the full ProductController on [codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/dVBuZ)

And the update form is [codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/puPED)
As you can see, I'm using array to insert the image to database and the array has been defined on `$product['images4'] = $images[3];`

This is where the picture was placed.
[image: This is where the picture was placed.]

But it gave me error:

```
ErrorException in ProductController.php line 149: Undefined offset: 0
```

Can you suggest a better code or explain me about the error? Thanks a lot ;)
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *undefined offset* arises when you try to access the **index** of an image that is not uploaded.

> To fix this problem, you should modify your code like this -

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $update = $request->all();
    $product = Product::find($id);

    $picture = ''; 
    $images = [];
    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
      $files = $request->file('images');
      foreach($files as $file){
        if (isset($file)){
          $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $picture = date('His').$filename;
          $destinationPath = base_path() . '\public\images/';
          $file->move($destinationPath, $picture);
          array_push($images, $picture);
        }
      }
    }

    if (!empty($product['images']) && isset($images[0])) {
      $update['images'] = $images[0];
    } 
    if (!empty($product['images2']) && isset($images[1])) {
      $update['images2'] = $images[1];
    } 
    if (!empty($product['images3']) && isset($images[2])) {
      $update['images3'] = $images[2];
    }
    if (!empty($product['images4']) && isset($images[3])) {
      $update['images4'] = $images[3];
    } 
    unset($update['images']);
    $product->update($update);
    return redirect('product');
}
```

Comment: Hi, it's give me `preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array`

Comment: @PutriDewiPurnamasari which line? Try copying and pasting the whole code (I've made and edit)

Comment: ErrorException in helpers.php line 740:

Comment: Dude @PutriDewiPurnamasari which line in your freaking controller -_-
Also, have you copied and pasted the entire code, notice that I've changed the *!empty* to **isset**

Comment: Lol sorry, it gave me different error no `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\laracom\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php on line 169 and defined`

Comment: @PutriDewiPurnamasari try copying and pasting the code again, I've made some changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110216/discussion-between-putri-dewi-purnamasari-and-atefth).

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r($image); exit;` after foreach close and check array with kay and value and arrange it

Comment: It gave me `Array ( [0] => 4 )`

Comment: `print_r($image); exit;` write outside for each